# See calendar overlay in All Events view

Tags: calendar, overlay

I have an overlay on a calendar and I am able to see the events in calendar view but not in the All Events list view. Is there a way for the overlay calendar to show in the All Events view? Or is the calendar view the only view that it works on?

Answer (score 1):

Overlays are for the calendar views only. The AllEvents view is a standard list view and so will only show the items for the calendar list it is associated with.

If you want to combine multiple calendars in a list then you'll need to use either the Content by Query web part or the Content by Search web part.